# How to set value on object on formbuilder inside another - Typescript

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want to access an existing formBuilder and set value of a specific object.
The problem is that is not a normal formbuilder. It is a formbuilder inside another.

code:

```
  formBuilder.group({
      nasty: formBuilder.group({
        myobject: ['', []],
      })});
```

How can I set value on myobject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a `FormGroup` within a `FormGroup`.

You could just `patchValue` whole form object.

```
this.form.patchValue({ nasty: { myobject: 'POPULATED' }})
```

Or you could target specific one.

```
this.form.get('nasty.something').patchValue('AND THIS TOO');
```

Here is StackBlitz with example -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3wpxsy