# Create a dynamic key per user Input using FormGroup Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have a form as follows:
[image: Form UI]

Within the dropdown list are certain pre-defined string values. The `Sensor's MAC Address` input field has a Pattern check regex.

### Goal

I wish to create an object as follows:

```
{
  'MAC_1': 'location2',
  'MAC_2': 'location3'
}
```

where the `MAC` is entered by the user and `location` comes from dropdown list.

Based on a [SE Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931988/how-to-set-value-on-object-on-formbuilder-inside-another-typescript) it is possible to insert values using `patchValue` but in the example it only *patches* the values to an existing key.

How Do I achieve this using Angular Forms?

I have followed the [Medium.com Blog on Angular-in-Depth](https://blog.angularindepth.com/unleash-the-power-of-forms-with-angulars-reactive-forms-d6be5918f408) to create reactive forms.

#### code snippet

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    dynamicForm: FormGroup;

    macPattern = '^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$';

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dynamicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            filters: this.formBuilder.array([])
          });
        this.addFilterToFiltersFormArray();
     }


    createFilterGroup() {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
          mac: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(this.macPattern)),
          loc: []
        });
    }

    get filtersFormArray() {
        return (this.dynamicForm.get('filters') as FormArray);
    }

    addFilterToFiltersFormArray() {
        this.filtersFormArray.push(this.createFilterGroup());
    }

    removeFilterFromFiltersFormArray(index) {
        this.filtersFormArray.removeAt(index);
    }

    getFilterGroupAtIndex(index) {
        return (this.filtersFormArray.at(index) as FormGroup);
    }

    save() {
        console.log(this.dynamicForm.value);
    }
}
```

which provides me results as follows:

```
{
  filters: [
     {
       mac: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF,
       loc: location_1
     }
  ]
}
```

#### Example Data

```
[
  filters: 
   {
        {
        mac: 'AA:BB:CC:11:22:DD',
        loc: 'urn:epc:iot:Business.1'
        },
        {
        mac: 'AB:23:24:C3:31:23',
        loc: 'urn:epc:iot:Business.3'
        }
  }
]
```

Comment: Please share some sample data to work with.

Comment: @SiddAjmera you are the author of the blog post arent you! I have edited the query with some sample data for the Mac Address and location

Comment: So to be clear, you have an array of filters that you want to populate your form with. But the user can still add more filters and once the form gets submitted, you want to read the value as an array?

Comment: Actually I do not have any seed data I solely rely on the user to enter the MAC address whilst the locations usually come from a REST call to a backend which just provides an array of location strings. I wish that when the user clicks save, initially I could just console log the desired object, and if it works then send it to the backend via POST

Comment: My thought was if it was possible directly to achieve the desired output via the `FormGroup` controls and not to post-process it. @SiddAjmera
but I guess I can anyways change this within the `Save` Button function call

Comment: The final form data would be obtained only once the user clicks on the save button. And since `filters` is implemented as a `FormArray` it's value would be an array. So you will have to post-process the form value to achieve the desired Object Structure. I don't really think there's any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to map the results to an Object. But the Reactive Form will give you an array. So just write a mapping function that does that for you.

Here, give this a try:

```js
const formData = {
  filters: [{
      mac: 'AA: BB: CC: DD: EE: FF',
      loc: 'location_1'
    },
    {
      mac: 'AB:23:24:C3:31:23',
      loc: 'urn:epc:iot:Business.3'
    }
  ]
};

const desiredData = {};
formData.filters.forEach(filter => {
  desiredData[filter.mac] = filter.loc;
})

console.log(desiredData);
```